# How to filter 'reports/product_collection' by user group id or customer group id. My code is here,

Tags: magento-1.9

```
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $customerGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
        $productsIds = Mage::getModel('amgroupcat/usergroup')->getProducts($customerGroupId);
        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addOrderedQty()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productsIds))
            ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc'); // most best sellers on top
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
```

I have used this `->addAttributeToFilter('group_id', array('in' => $customerGroupId))` and `->addAttributeToFilter('customer_group_id', array('in' => $customerGroupId))` but not work and showing this error **Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean in /data/htdocs/public_html/latitude/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816**.